# Errors compiling PHP 5.5 with VC9

Tags: php, apache, x86

According with the information on the page https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/compiler I'm trying to compile PHP5.5 for the VC9-x86 support - I absolutely need this version.

It should work, as stated in the page.

I'm follogin the instruction on the page https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild but I receive a number of errors:

```
ext\standard\info.c(502) : error C2065: 'PRODUCT_SERVER_FOUNDATION' : undeclared  identifier
ext\standard\info.c(502) : error C2051: case expression not constant
ext\standard\info.c(532) : error C2065: 'PRODUCT_STORAGE_EXPRESS_SERVER_CORE' : undeclared identifier
ext\standard\info.c(532) : error C2051: case expression not constant
ext\standard\info.c(535) : error C2065: 'PRODUCT_STORAGE_STANDARD_SERVER_CORE' :
 undeclared identifier
ext\standard\info.c(535) : error C2051: case expression not constant
ext\standard\info.c(538) : error C2065: 'PRODUCT_STORAGE_WORKGROUP_SERVER_CORE'
: undeclared identifier
ext\standard\info.c(538) : error C2051: case expression not constant
ext\standard\info.c(541) : error C2065: 'PRODUCT_STORAGE_ENTERPRISE_SERVER_CORE'
 : undeclared identifier
ext\standard\info.c(541) : error C2051: case expression not constant
ext\standard\info.c(544) : error C2065: 'PRODUCT_STARTER_N' : undeclared identif
ier
ext\standard\info.c(544) : error C2051: case expression not constant
ext\standard\info.c(547) : error C2065: 'PRODUCT_PROFESSIONAL' : undeclared iden
tifier
ext\standard\info.c(547) : error C2051: case expression not constant
ext\standard\info.c(550) : error C2065: 'PRODUCT_PROFESSIONAL_N' : undeclared id
entifier
ext\standard\info.c(550) : error C2051: case expression not constant
```

How can i solve?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue ... after plowing through gobs and gobs of hacks to get to this point.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i find a solution.

The reported constants are not defines for a simple reason: the SDK6.1 does not include them.
The constants are defined in the file C:\php-sdk\phpdev\vc9\x86\php-5.5.30-src\ext\standard\winver.h but they are conditioned by a constant value that always exists:

```
#ifndef PRODUCT_ULTIMATE
```

I changed this with the first missing constant as:

```
#ifndef PRODUCT_STORAGE_EXPRESS_SERVER_CORE // SM PRODUCT_ULTIMATE
```

In plus I've added a missing value some rows below:

```
#define PRODUCT_STARTER_E                           0x00000042  //SM
```

In this way I'm able to compile both php.exe and php.lib library.